# How many throws of a die until every possible result is obtained?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

> A die is thrown until every possible result (i.e., every integer from 1 to 6) is obtained. Find the expected value of the number of throws.

How do I do that? I understand that probability for the single result is $\{1, 5/6, \ldots , 1/6\}$, but what about the expected value?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266505/a-number-of-dice-rolls-to-see-every-number-at-least-once

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: I had forgotten that I wrote an answer to that question.

Comment: @robjohn Well, with over 4000 answers you can't be expected to keep track of them all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very popular problem. I learned it as the ["collector's problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).

Essentially, you want to model rolling a die until a new face is shown
as a geometric distribution with $p_k = \frac{7-k}{6}$ where $k = 1,\dotsc,6$ is the number of faces you have seen. So, if $X_k$ denotes rolling until you see $k$th different face, then $X_k\sim\text{Geom}(p_k)$ on $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. It follows that $X = X_1+\dotsb+X_6$ is the number of rolls until you have seen all six faces. Then
$$E[X] = E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dotsb+E[X_6] = \frac{6}{6}+\frac{6}{5}+\dotsb+\frac{6}{1}=14.7.$$

Comment: why not $p_k\in \{ 1, 5/6, 4/6, 3/6, 2/6, 1/6\}$?

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: Still i  do not get it why expectation is $1/p_k$?

Comment: A random variable that follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p$ on $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ has mean equal to $\frac{1}{p}$. This is a well-known fact.

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for face $k$, the probability of rolling faces already rolled is $\frac{k-1}n$. Therefore, the expected number of rolls to get face $k$, after rolling face $k-1$, is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\overbrace{\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)^{j-1}}^{\text{roll $j-1$ already rolled}}\ \ \overbrace{\frac{n-k+1}n\vphantom{\left(\frac kn\right)^1}}^{\text{roll $1$ not rolled}}\,j
&=\frac{n-k+1}n\frac1{\left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{n}{n-k+1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the expected number of rolls to get all the faces is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n-k+1}
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&\sim n\log(n)+\gamma n+\frac12-\frac1{12n}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). The asymptotic expansion is gotten using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

For a $6$-sided die, the expected number of rolls is exactly $14.7$.

Using the terms given in the asymptotic expansion for $n=6$ gives $14.69996$.  The approximation gets better for larger $n$.

Comment: Following Byron Schmuland's comment, I see that I wrote [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/266578), which evaluates the expected number of rolls in another way.